# Getting Website URL using JS not working with https

Tags: javascript, url, https, get

I'm using this JS code to get the page url, title and send them to the server to store them in a database, like a button you bookmarked in your browser toolbar and click it on any website you have open and it will get the website's URL and TITLE.

However this code is working great BUT it's not working with (https) url

```
javascript:(function(){var jsScript=document.createElement('script');
jsScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
jsScript.setAttribute('src', 'bookmark.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsScript);
})();
```

It's working good with all url's Except (https) links like
https://facebook.com 
https://google.com

It's not working at all with these kind of links.

Any improvements that could make it work with https links?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of browser are you using? Did you check some output in debugger? Is there are errors? Can you provide some other information.

Comment: You`ll always have problems getting HTTPS URL, unless the server your are sending data is also HTTPS...

Comment: @antindexer i try it on all major browsers
No Errors in http requests 
nothing all work perfect except getting https
ask anything and i will answer it

Comment: @bodi0 You mean my server SHOULD have ssl certificate so i can get the https links ?

Comment: What about debugger window in chrome?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what you need. However, facebook, google still have http:// access enabled, although this URL is converted automatically to https://, so you *might* be able to fetch some of those requests.

Comment: @antindexer
Windows: CTRL-SHIFT-J

Mac: ALT-⌘-J

Comment: @bodi0 Will try to test it 
Thank You a Lot
Please write it in answer so i can make it the beast answer

Comment: @bodi0 You Are Right it's working perfect in secure server 
thank you Please Write your comment in answer so i can make it best answer

Thank You again

Comment: Already done, glad that I have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You`ll always have problems getting HTTPS URL, unless the server your are sending data is also HTTPS. Your server may need SSL certificate in order to complete the task. 
However, facebook, google still have http:// access enabled, although this URL is converted automatically to https://, so you might be able to fetch some of those requests.

Edit: This is because so called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (CORS).

Answer (score 0):

use your all personal js. don't take from any external link js and css.
if you have all css and js in your project folder then it will work properly.
thank you